# How to plot two columns on one line graph using pandas and seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot columns `High` and `Low` into the same line graph using seaborn.

They are from the same csv file. I managed to graph `High` on the y-axis but I am struggling to get the `Low` in.

For reference, the files are from Kaggle.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid")

# Read Data from CSV:
micro = pd.read_csv('Microsoft Corporationstock.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])
covid = pd.read_csv('day_wise.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])

# Filter Data Needed:
start_date = covid['Date'].loc[0]
index_date = int(micro[micro['Date'] == start_date].index.values)

# Microsoft Stock Plot:
mg = sns.relplot(x='Date', y='High', kind='line', data=micro.loc[index_date:])
mg.set_xticklabels(rotation=30)
plt.ylabel('Market Value')
mg.fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

[High Stock Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zmjR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general seaborn plots work better in "melted" format.

Here you can [**`melt`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) the data into `Date`, `Type` (High or Low), and `Market Value`. Then use `y='Market Value'` and `hue='Type'` to get both High and Low in the same plot:

```py
mg = sns.relplot(
    data=micro.loc[index_date:].melt(id_vars='Date', var_name='Type', value_name='Market Value')),
    x='Date',
    y='Market Value',
    hue='Type',
    kind='line',
)
```

Comment: I had to specify that I only want to load in 'High' and 'Low' to get it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does changing it to this work? If it's similar to matplotlib it might.

```
plot_y = ['High', 'Low']

for y in plot_y:
    mg = sns.relplot(x='Date', y=y, kind='line', data=micro.loc[index_date:])
    mg.fig.autofmt_xdate()
    mg.set_xticklabels(rotation=30)

plt.ylabel('Market Value')
plt.show()
```